# iOS landscape @media query issues

Tags: css, ios, webkit, media

I've created a simple site that I'm attempting to make responsive - it can be viewed at http://www.teamlist.co.  I've used @media queries to target iOS, and it looks fine in portrait orientation, but doesn't fit to width:100% in landscape.  I've found this to be true on both an iPhone 4 and an iPad.  Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't they target screen sizes and not iOS? From what I recall seeing about them you may need to target all the widths that would be available

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  I'm targeting the screen size/device. I've now realized that it's actually recognizing the @media query itself, it's just not recognizing the width, which is set at 100%.

Comment: That is interesting. Sorry I'm not familiar with deeper iOS web design like that, good luck to ya though.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I discovered that this is a long-standing bug in the iOS, but Scott at the Filament group has developed an interesting workaround script that I'm trying. Included it on my offending page and it seems to do the trick:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/

You can find the code on github:

https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix#readme

So far, it's a lifesaver!